# Visual Studio 2012 - break when errno set

Tags: c++, c, visual-studio, visual-studio-2012, breakpoints

I'm getting a domain error somewhere in a couple of hundred lines of code and I'd like to find which line is causing it.  My first thought was to set a data breakpoint on `_errno()` (since the `errno` macro expands to `*_errno()`, I reasoned that `_errno()` should give the address where the errno error code is stored).  However, Visual Studio complains that the identifier `_errno` is undefined.

What is the correct way to break when errno is set in Visual Studio?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is a *function*, not a variable.  It returns a pointer to an int, you need to know that pointer value to set a data breakpoint.

Best way to go about it is to write this line of code at the start of main():

```
 errno = 0;
```

And set a breakpoint on the next line.  Switch to the disassembly window, it typically resembles this:

```
011013C0  call        dword ptr [__imp___errno (11082BCh)] 
011013C6  cmp         esi,esp 
011013C8  call        @ILT+320(__RTC_CheckEsp) (1101145h) 
011013CD  mov         dword ptr [eax],0
```

So in my case, the EAX register has the address to set the data breakpoint on.  Just check once if your code is similar.  Use the @eax pseudo variable in the dialog, like this:

[image]

Comment: Fantastic solution.  If I'm correct, the return address should always be stored in eax, so switching to the disassembly window shouldn't even be necessary.

Comment: You'll need to check if your code looks similar.  I don't know, you didn't specify your compiler version or build settings.